# Why does my XMLHttpRequest have readystate 4 but status 0?

Tags: javascript, post, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I have a content script in my Chrome extension which runs on some HTTPS page. It is trying to send a POST request to an HTTP page (by means of a background script) which is a route for an API that I have set up. I am trying to send JSON data over. However I am getting status 0, even though the ready state is 4. I used Postman to perform the same post and it worked. This leads me to believe it is a HTTPS protocol issue, however I am performing a GET on an HTTP page in the same background script and that is working fine. What might be the issue then? Here is my POST code:

```
var string = json;
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { 
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    }
};
xhr.send(string);
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I used the chrome developer tools to debug the background script and I found the error, which was "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.". I guess background script errors do not print to the main console.

UPDATE:

I had to add the site I was posting to to the permissions field in my manifest. It works now.

Comment: There is no such thing like 0 status code.Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Response_codes

Comment: Regardless, when I enter the onreadystatechange function and check xhr.status, it is 0.

Comment: A status of 0 usually means the request was aborted, either [intentionally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#abort()) or due to interruption (e.g. navigation causing the page to be unloaded). The request is as "complete" as it's going to be (so, `readyState === 4`), but no response was ever received to set a different status.

Comment: @gtsioni Updated my answer. If you want to discuss other ways for debugging the AJAX error, we can chat sometime.

Comment: I have also seen this in response to an OPTIONS call, the ajax layer reports status 0 but Fiddler is shows a 500 (and raw response shows 500) with a valid html body describing the error.

Answer (score 7):

I have a similar issue and, after debugging it for days, the only solution I found was to make the XMLHttpRequest synchronous by setting set the [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) param in the XMLHttpRequest open method to false.

Comment: Why would that help?

Comment: This solved my problem when trying to use WKWebView with XMLHttpRequest to download a blob url. I tried setting various access headers to no avail, but this worked.

Comment: Solved my problem, too. My code worked fine on Chromium. But Safari always reported status 0 after the POST Request, messing up my error handling. Firefox didn't even succeed in fulfilling that REST POST at all. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: That fixed the problem for me as well, but unfortunately synchronous XMLHttpRequests are now deprecated, according to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest_API/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Answer (score 2):

The readyState value of 4 means the operation completed successfully **or failed**. The status property is initialized to 0 and will remain at 0 if an error occurs. Assign an event handler to the `xhr.onerror` property and I bet you'll see that handler fire. **Unfortunately, the error event doesn't give any useful information about what caused the error.**

To find out what caused the error, I would use the debug tools found in Chrome. Menu => More tools => Developer Tools. Then go to the "Network" tab. There you can see all the HTTP requests your webpage has made. It will show better details on any errors there.

Comment: I am kind of inexperienced at this, and I'm having a hard time interpreting the page you linked me. What might a working error handler look like? Thanks!

Comment: I was able to set up an onerror function handler and the event.detail is undefined.

Comment: Is there no way to get error details from the error object or xhr object itself? Is browser debug tools really the only way?

Comment: As Jon Anderson told , I see Network tab but nothing to tell more than debugging mode just say "error"

Comment: For my case, the error happens on a remote server, I would like to see the actual error information, what should I do? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

What did you do?

I had to add the site I was posting to the permissions field in my manifest. It works now.

```
XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "the api website"); ?
```

Comment: I think he meant adding it to the manifest.json that goes in the header of the html -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions

Answer (score -1):

In mky case I got the status 0', becvause I used a javascript onClickButton() function on a form, so two gets!